# How to filter List in Java using stream comparing 2 list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, filter, java-stream

I try to filter a list in java using streams. But it is not working and the IDE do not show suggested methods.

I have a list called `userServices` and the elements in it has a method called `getServiceName`, I want to filter that I want to make a new list that includes the elements whose name is not in the another list that called `expensesOftheUser`.

```
    List<UserServices> userServices = policyService.getAllUserServicesForMoveStage(employee.getPolicyVersionId(), null, false, false);
        List<Expense> expensesOftheUser = expenseService.getExpensesByUserId(employee.getUserId(),employee.getMoveId());

// here I try to filter to a new list but I don't see any IDE suggestion
List<UserService> filteredUserServices = userServices.stream()
              .filter(c -> c.getServiceName != expensesOftheUser.getServiceName)
              .collect(toList());
```

But it is not working. How can I filter it and make a new list?

edit: lists types are different but the compared properties are all string

Comment: Does `getServiceName` return a `String`? If yes - you should use `equals` to compare.

Comment: what *type* of list is `expensesOftheUser`? and what does the method `getServiceName` return?

Comment: all returns string

Comment: I have edited the code.

Comment: You forgot to specify the class in which the factory method for List-Collectors lies in. Try `Collectors.toList()` instead. This is a common issue since most IDEs accept `toList()`and convert it to `Collectors.toList()` on-the-fly. Thus, most people do NOT recognize that `toList()` isn't sufficient.

Comment: @Quaffel That is not the issue with the code. A `static import` would resolve that anyway. Apart from which accessing `expensesOftheUser.getServiceName` certainly is, since `List` interface doesn't expose any such APIs and the OP is forgetting that he/she is not iterating over the same collection.

Comment: As he or she added the Lists' declaration after or while I've written the comment, I didn't notice that `expensesOftheUser` is of type `List`.

Comment: Nonetheless, using static imports for Collectors is, at least imh, a bad practice and should therefore be avoided.